# How to decrypt .pgp file stored in Google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, private-key, pgp, encryption-asymmetric

I have a .pgp file stored in bucket in Google cloud storage.
I want to decrypt it with private key and store it back to new target folder in GCS.
is there a way we can do this?

Answer (score -1):

Is not possible to make changes directly on Google Cloud Storage (GCS), to decrypt and save your files is necessary download your file, decrypt locally and upload the decrypted file.

i think that this code will be useful for your use case:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, local_file, destination_blob_name):
   #bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
   #source_blob_name = "storage-object.pgp"
   #local_file = "local/storage-object.pgp"

   #Download your file from your bucket
   storage_client = storage.Client()

   bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
   blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
   blob.download_to_filename(local_file)

   # put your code to decrypt your file

   #Upload your decrypted file from local
   destination_blob_name= "/decrypted_files/storage-object.pgp"
   blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
   blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)
```